# Creating a constrained log function

Tags: functions, logarithms

Good morning,

I have a series of values that I intend to use as the exponents and I would like to create a log function so that:

- $Log_x(y_1)=.1$
- $Log_x(y_2)=.2$
- $Log_x(y_3)=.3$
- ...
- $Log_x(y_{15})=1$

Where $y_1=50$ and $y_{15}=400$ --> These are my constraints.

If you could provide any insight, that would be greatly appreciated.

Best,
Bernardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't stated any relationship between $y_i$, the only possible known value are:
$$
x^{0.1}=50,
$$
$$
x^{1}=400,
$$
For every $i=2,\dots,14$ you have the relationships:
$$
x^{0.2}=y_2,
$$
$$
x^{0.3}=y_3,
$$
$$
\vdots
$$

Comment: So you are suggesting that I should define a function between the $Y_i$?

Comment: Well, it depends. If you know $x$, you can try some kind of linear regression on $y_i$. Otherwise I didn't understand the problem properly. Denote $x_1=x^{0.1},\dots x_{15}=x^{1}$, and do the linear regression between $X_i=\log(x_i)$ and $y_i$.

Comment: Actually, I don't know X at all. For Y, all I know is that it has to be between 50 (min) and 400 (max). And I know the exponents I want to use (.1, .2, .3...). I guess I don't have enough elements to solve it?

Comment: If $x$ is constant, I'm afraid it cannot be solved: the first relation reads $x=50^{1/10}$, whilst the second one reads $x=400$, which says that your system is not compatible. Probably $x$ is $x_i$, but you need to know one between ${x_i}_i$ and ${y_i}_i$.

Comment: Yeah that's what I feared. Thanks, appreciate the clarification.